# How to Monitor Docker All Container CPU/Disk/Memory Usage in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, monitoring, grafana

I want to monitor
container cpu usage,
container disk usage and
container memory usage

And

Server CPU Usage
Server Memory Usage and
Server Harddisk Usage

Actually i have one server in that 40 container are running and in that server i have install prometheus, grafana, node exporter, cadvisor and alertmanager for monitoring my 40 container and server usage both

I have setup container cpu usage and memory usage but not getting about disk usage of container

Even i have setup email alert but that also properly not triggering into my gmail account

Below is email alert coming into my gmail account

```
7] Firing
Labels
alertname = High_Memory_Usage_1g
container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id = r7r41ngp9zw6wgb4fcc289087
container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name = xxxxx-app.1.mj9vo4024v4d30evq1r2xm2n6
Annotations
description = app_notes-app.1.mj9vo4024v4d30evq1r2xm2n6 on 'r7r41ngp9zw6wgb4fcc289087' memory usage is 812.9MB.
summary = Memory alert for Swarm task 'app_notes-app.1.mj9vo4024v4d30evq1r2xm2n6' on 'r7r41ngp9zw6wgb4fcc289087'
Source
Labels
alertname = High_Memory_Usage_1g
container_label_com_docker_swarm_node_id = r7r41ngp9zw6wgb4fcc289087
container_label_com_docker_swarm_task_name = dev_fx-xxxx-xxx.1.6k0qavdj4mf3qe6fnspx2dh0h
Annotations
description = dev_fxxxxxxx.1.6k0qavdj4mf3qe6fnspx2dh0h on 'r7r41ngp9zw6wgb4fcc289087' memory usage is 3.701GB.
```

Please do let me know to do it

Comment: can you add configuration for the mentioned software tools?

Comment: @NoamYizraeli what configuration u need i have alertmanger.yml, alert.rules, container.yml, diskusage.yml, docker-compose.yml and prometheus.yml file -- all this yaml im using for grafana and promethues to monitor my server and docker container usage

Comment: any grafana configuration is probably non-essential because it only displays data, please attach any configuration related to the production and collection of the metrics in question

Comment: ok but what u need related to prod and collection of metrics.  U need Node Exporter metrics?

Comment: None of the metrics themselfs, maybe the node exporter runtime command with it's options